# How to use native google-map/marker-clusterer in angular 2+ component

Tags: angular, google-maps, markerclusterer

I want to use google maps in my Angular projects. I use [AGM](https://angular-maps.com) but lib is missing option for getting references on all markers on cluster click. So I decided to use native google maps.

---

I installed `npm install @google/maps --save`  then I need typing so I used `npm install @types/google-maps ---save` . Finally, as I want to get all markers from cluster, I installed `npm install markerclustererplus --save` and types `npm install --save @types/markerclustererplus`.

---

my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import '@google/maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-map-native',
  templateUrl: './google-map-native.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-map-native.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleMapNativeComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('googleMapContainer') googleMapContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    const options = {
      'zoom': 13,
      'center': center,
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    const map: google.maps.Map = new google.maps.Map(this.googleMapContainer.nativeElement, options);

    console.log(map);
  }

}
```

html template

```
<div #googleMapContainer fxFlexFill>

</div>
```

When I lauch the app I am getting an error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at GoogleMapNativeComponent.ngOnInit (google-map-native.component.ts:16)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12095)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (GoogleMapNativeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
```

How can I correctly include library to my component and api key?

Comment: Sounds like the Google Maps JavaScript API didn't finish loading when you try to access the google.maps.LatLng in the  ngOnInit(). Where is the script tag that loads an API? Does this script have a callback function to be called once the API is loaded?

Comment: I also added import '@google/maps'; but  it did not helped

Comment: Here is an answer to this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592186/4332063](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592186/4332063)

Comment: No it is not. I use native google map. This is refering to AGM

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late but for anyone reaching this question:

Ok first, two checks you should do:

- did you import the googlemaps js script from anywhere? It can be in your index.html file or in angular cli json
- did you add googlemaps to your "types" array in tsconfig?

Second, there's a problem in your code.
You should only use ViewChild variables on/after your ngAfterViewInit method (don't forget to add it to your component's implements list), and not on your ngOnInit.
So, you cannot create your map on the ngOnInit method, it will not work.

Also, as of today, you should install "@types/googlemaps" and not @types/google-maps. Additionally, it worked for me when installing it only for devDependencies (--save-dev)